# NetworkManager does not save wifi passwords

Tags: networkmanager, d-bus

I'm trying to use D-bus method `AddAndActivate` connection on interface `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager` to create a wifi connection. I definitely pass a PreSharedKey field with the password, but NetworkManager ignores this field, fails on connection activation and asks for a password when I try to use `nmcli c up <Connection>`.

Any ideas how to force it to save the password?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the files in the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` directory.

All WiFi connections are stored here.
Try to append the password manually.

Here is an example of my config:

```
[connection]
id=<SSID>
uuid=<UUID>
type=wifi
interface-name=<INTERFACE>
permissions=

[wifi]
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=infrastructure
ssid=xxxxx

[wifi-security]
auth-alg=open
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=XXXXXXX                       <- Enter password here

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto

[proxy]
```

Comment: This would be a workaround...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution on how to create and activate connections programmatically and do not be asked for password on activation.
Instead of `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.AddAndActivateConnection()` you can use `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Settings.AddConnection()` and then just call `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.ActivateConnection()`. You will not be asked for password